# InvalidProgramException in System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime after KB2742595

Tags: iis-7.5

When ever I install the security Patch KB2742595 on my web server I'm start getting the " Exception type: InvalidProgramException

```
    Exception message: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime..ctor(String contractName, String contractNamespace)"

Stack trace:    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime..ctor(String contractName, String contractNamespace)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.BuildProxyBehavior(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, BindingParameterCollection& parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.BuildChannelFactory(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, Boolean useActiveAutoClose)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.CreateFactory()
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.OnOpening()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open()
```

The configuration is W Server 2K8 SP1 and communicating the WCF service over nettcp.
Please help.